# Is it possible to use Google Play Service on a game not published on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-services

I'm developing a game for a local Android market but for the leaderboard I'm using Google Play Services. I wanted to know whether it's possible for people to use my leaderboard without publishing on Google Play and just on that local Android market.

Problem is I got Leaderboard up and running with the GPGS but only testers can use it and I think for others be able to use it has to be out of beta and published, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Best, idn

Answer (score 2):

I think not, **some times ago it was possible using it on iOS apps** (and hence it was possible using also elsewhere), but now they deprecated the API.

I think they have no particular incentive on getting it work on other platforms but Google Play.

So basically **you have the following choice:**

1. implement your server infrastructure for your simple game
2. use the service only for Android games published in Play Store.

The service relies on remote communication, that means that theorically it is possible to get it working almost anywhere, in practice that is hard to do, and not the best maintenable option.

I think that's a smart move because most programmers to avoid problems will just stick on using it on Play Store.